# ElasticSearch aggs returns 10 buckets only

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am running an aggs query and specifying the size of 100, but ES only returns 10 buckets back. Why? What am I missing?

```
{   
  "size": 100
   ,"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "term": {"app": "cnn"} }
        ]
      }
    }
   ,"aggs": {
    "unique_client": {
      "terms": {"field": "client"}    
      }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the top size parameter to zero to signify that it is an aggregation. The number of buckets returned is set by specifying the size INSIDE the terms aggregation braces.

```
{   
  "size": 0
   ,"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "term": {"app": "cnn"} }
        ]
      }
    }
   ,"aggs": {
    "unique_client": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "client",
        "size" : 100
      }
     }     
    }
}
```

If you set it to 0 the value will default to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Thank you, both. I gave Vanlightly credit as he responded fist.

Comment: Actually I responded second but the JSON in ChintanShah25's answer has a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

**outer size** is for total number of documents you get back for your query, so size = 100 returns 100 documents, for getting 100 aggregations bucket, specify size **inside** your *unique_client* aggs like this

```
{   
  "size": 0
   ,"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "term": {"app": "cnn"} }
        ]
      }
    }
   ,"aggs": {
    "unique_client": {
      "terms": {"field": "client"},
      "size" : 100
      }     
    }
}
```

By Default size of aggregations is 10, that is why you get 10 results, I have made outer size = 0 to get only aggregations.

Comment: Hi ,Can you help me figure out  this .I have like 1 million records in elastic search and I am applying above aggregation .I want all aggregation buckets may be 0.5 million but that gives me a timeout ,how to do this process ?? .I adopted the strategy of requesting 50k buckets at a time then shifting the data in other index after processing ,and then deleting the original data but thats not giving me proper results ,any idea how to do this?